# Remove the leading zero before a number in python

Tags: python

I have a string which correspond to a number but with several leading zeros before it. What I want to do is to remove the zeros that are before the number but not in the number. For example "00000001" should be 1 and "00000010" should be 10. I wrote  code that remove zeros but also the tailing one:

```
segment = my_str.strip("0")
```

That code removes all zeros. How can I only remove the leading zeros before the number.

Comment: `strip` removes leading and trailing, `lstrip` removes leading

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use `lstrip`:

```
>>> '00000010'.lstrip('0')
'10'
```

(`strip` removes both leading and trailing zeros.)

This messes up `'0'` (turning it into an empty string). There are several ways to fix this:

#1:

```
>>> re.sub(r'0+(.+)', r'\1', '000010')
'10'
>>> re.sub(r'0+(.+)', r'\1', '0')
'0'
```

#2:

```
>>> str(int('0000010'))
'10'
```

#3:

```
>>> s = '000010'
>>> s[:-1].lstrip('0') + s[-1]
```

Comment: Or just call `int`, `int('00000010')`. will also work for `'0'` :)

Answer (score 5):

just use the `int()` function, it will change the string into an integer and remove the zeros

```py
my_str = '00000010'    
my_int = int(my_str)    
print(my_int)
```

output:

```
10
```

Comment: Note that if you need to keep the value a string for whatever reason, you can do the opposite conversion to get it back: `str(int('00000010'))`